# How to write the unit test for service layer which is calling another external API in javascript

Tags: unit-testing

How should I write test unit test for `searchName` function as I should not call the real external API
My service.ts is like below:

```
    @Service()
    export class StudentService{
      public async searchName(param1,param2):Promise<any>{
        const data = this.parsetoXmlRequest(param1,param2)
        const config:AxiosRequestConfig = {
         url: some_url,
         method: post,
         data: data,
         responseType:json
    } 
     try{
      const réponse = await axios(config);
      return response.data;
     }catch(error){}
    }
 
   private parsetoXmlRequest(param1,param2){
   // Here is codes to parse json into xml format for request body 
}
```

Should I mock the external api response and what is the step of doing it? Appreciate for the help

Answer (score 0):

You should test `parsetoXmlRequest`, probably do not want to declare it private.
This example should work.

```
import { StudentService } from './path/to/StudentService';


describe('StudentService', () => {
  let service: new StudentService(); 

  it('should correctly convert JSON to XML', () => {
    const result = (service as any).parsetoXmlRequest('param1Value', 'param2Value');

    // Assert the expected XML output (simple example) 
    expect(result).toBe('expected XML string');
  });
});
```